# Read from XLSX (Excel 2007-2010) file from VB.NET 2008

Tags: .net, vb.net, excel, excel-2010, vba

i have created an application in VB.Net 2008 for reading a value from MS excel 2007 and processing some transaction in another application and writing an output in same excel sheet(next column of input value).

i am used OLEDB for connection and extracting values.

it is working fine in Excel 2007/2003. But in Excel 2010  application is not working properly.

can you tell me what to do ?

regards,
Madhan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=c:\myFolder\myExcel2007file.xlsx;Extended Properties="Excel 12.0;HDR=YES";

btw. First hit in google, Connection string changed for xlsx

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim path As String = "c:\A.xlsx"

Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 ;Data Source=" & path & ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1;'
```